# Probability of clicks gone up

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have two sets of values which are "number of clicks per day" for current and last month. I want to know the probability that the number of clicks have gone up this month. In Python this might translate to:

```
last_month_clicks = [355, 221, 302, ...]
current_month_clicks = [550, 537, 404, ...]
p = p_all_values_in_dist(last_month_clicks, current_month_clicks)
```

I don't know what distribution might be suitable (and I'm not very familiar with scipy). Thanks in advance!

Comment: the probability that "the number of clicks have gone up this month" (or any other past-time event with a **known outcome**) is either $1$ or $0$!!!

Comment: @barakmanos: good call! That's not what I'm looking for. :)  I'm probably interested in odds against chance for the increase.

Comment: Well, IF you expect that the number of visitors should not seriously depend on the day of the month, you may plot a regression line through all the days of both months, with confidence intervals and check the trend. The more correct way is to do it like economists do: subtract the values at corresponding days, e.g. current month 1st - last month 1st, etc, and check the trend again.

Comment: @hcl14: Aha, and what to do after subtracting? How to check odds against chance that the clicks have increased (assuming a poisson distribution)?

Comment: The subtracting is needed to plot a better graph, reducing "seasonal" fluctuations (when there is more clicks on weekends, for example). You can check on the graph for strong picture of increase/decrease. 1) If you want to test a hypothesis, [here are couple of ways](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/145614/poisson-hypothesis-testing-for-two-parameters) of doing One-Tailed test to compare expectations if poisson distribution is assumed. The test will give you a p-value for desired significance level (say, 5%) = the probability that the correct hypothesis chosen is rejected.

Comment: 2) The simple idea of looking for definite decrease for a separate observation is described [here, under the "One-Tailed test" section](http://revisionmaths.com/advanced-level-maths-revision/statistics/one-and-two-tailed-tests). Maybe you may try to use the rounded mean from the second month or the last weeks here, the poisson parameters are taken from the previous month. But the new values should be really low/high to give a good result, it should be easily seen on the plot.

Comment: So, for example (I'm not sure that it is correct and the result obtained is truly meaningful) I can obtain $\lambda$ from the data of the first month, then compute the rounded mean $m$(or the median can be better) for the second month and check how the second value is likely to be obtained from the poisson distribution based on my $\lambda$:  $P_{\lambda}(X \leq m) =$ the probability that the value $m$ has come from a Poisson($\lambda$) distribution.